# How do I pass an object created in one class to another in java?

Tags: java, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm trying to develop an online hotel booking system.  I have the main class which takes input from the user such as their name, their payment information, and other data fields and makes a `Reservation` object using that information.  I have another class called `Room` that has a list of `Reservations` for each `Room` object.  The problem I am having is I can't figure out a way to add the `Reservation` object into the list in the `Room` object.  Here is some of the code:

```
public class HotelReservationSystem
{
    private Reservation reservation;

    public void makeReservation(int checkIn, int checkOut)//Other parameters
    {
        reservation = new Reservation(checkIn, checkOut);
    }
}

public class Room
{
    private ArrayList<Reservation> reservations;

    public void addReservation(//parameters?)
    {
        reservations.add(//parameter?);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to get the new `Reservation` object to be passed as a parameter for the `add` method in the `Room` class.
I just can't wrap my head around it and was hoping for someone to help jog my thinking process.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Uh, you'd use a reference.  Probably pass it as a parameter to addReservation.

Comment: And very likely you should not have the `reservation` instance variable but should carry that reference (the same one you'd pass to addReservation) as a local parameter in your method that is orchestrating the whole "create reservation" operation.

Comment: Think of HotelReservationSystem as a physical desk.  There would be only one.  There are a bunch of cubbyholes in the desk, one for each Room.  When you create a Reservation you stick it in the appropriate cubbyhole.  There is no one place on the desk that is a single reservation, except temporarily when the clerk (`makeReservation`) is writing it down, and that reservation is kept entirely within `makeReservation` until it's filed in a Room.

Comment: I'm a visual learned, so that example of the physical desk really helped me understand how to implement the design. Thank you for that different point of view!

Comment: I think it's always useful to view this sort of thing as a physical process.  Once you've got a handle on it you can maybe reduce it to a mathematical model of some sort, but you need to get that "handle" first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let makeReservation return the created Reservation object:

```
 public Reservation makeReservation(int checkIn, int checkOut)//Other parameters
{
    reservation = new Reservation(checkIn, checkOut);
    return reservation;
}
```

(You could also create a getter for `reservation`)

Then change your addReservation like this:

```
public void addReservation(Reservation res)
{
    reservations.add(res);
}
```

And then just add it like this:

```
HotelReservationSystem hrs = new HotelReservationSystem();
Reservation res = hrs.makeReservation();
Room room = new Room();
room.addReservation(res);
```

However, you might want to rethink your model. Right now your `HotelReservationSystem` is creating a reservation and only saves that one, overwriting old ones. What happens if you create more than one? Also how can you get the reservations for a certain room given the HotelReservationSystem object? Just some things to think about...

Comment: I know from the information i provided the model doesn't look so great, but I just needed the specific question answered. I left out a lot of other code that didn't really pertain to the question. The way I have it set up is a customer input their information.  That information is used to make a reservation.  That reservation is stored in a list that the room itself contains. Once it's stored, the rest of the implementation resets for the next user, but the room's list stays.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must have tried this

```
public void addReservation(Reservation reservation)
{
    reservations.add(reservation);
}
```

but the problem here is that your list `reservations` is null and will throw null pointer exception. So better initialize it at declaration. So change this

```
private ArrayList<Reservation> reservations;
```

to

```
private ArrayList<Reservation> reservations = new ArrayList<Reservation>();
```

And in your `makeReservation` method of `Hotel` class do this:

```
Room room = new Room();
room.addReservation(reservation);
```